# How to show dynamic data in footer of zend-framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework2

I want footer content to be dynamic i.e. I want some data to be shown from database but ,The footer can not be called by any controller it is just included in layout portion so .How can i get dynamic data in footer using database connectivity

```
<header>
<div class="container">
<?php include('header.phtml');?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<?php include('menu.phtml');?>
</nav>
<div class="clearfix"></div>


<div class="slider-home">
<?php include('slider.phtml');?>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

</header>
<!--Header End-->



<!--Container Start-->
<div class="container orange-panelbg">
<?php echo $this->content; ?>
</div>
<!--Container End-->

<!--Footer Start-->
<footer>
<div class="container">
<?php include('footer-widget.phtml'); ?>
</div>

<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="copyright">    
<div class="container">
<?php include('footer.phtml'); ?>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Here everything i call using controller an their actions will reflect changes in $this content so if ,I change the method then footer content will also be changed . How can i achieve this or rather i use core php mysql db connectivity ??

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article you can follow to fix this problem: http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/

Let me know if that helps, and if any further questions are raised.